# inserting a django form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

what I am trying to do is fairly simple:

I want to add `{{ form }}` to a table cell with javascript

this what I have but it only works for labels:

```
function showOrHideReconciliationTable() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("edit-inventory-reconciliation");   
      if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        var table = document.getElementById("main-table");
        var row = table.insertRow(7);
        row.classList.add("warehouse-row");
        row.setAttribute('id','table-toogle');
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = "{{ form }}";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
    } else {
        var table = document.getElementById("main-table");
        var row = table.deleteRow(7);
    }
```

any help would be appreciated (it's probably something simple or you cannot do it this way)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it was as simple as this (if anyone is interested):

```
  cell1.innerHTML = `
    {{ form }}
    `;
```